# Sharing variables between PHP files

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a set of logic in my plugin.php, and it ends with a result stored in a variable.

```
// Calculate rating averages
$args = array(
'ID' => $post_id,
'status' => 'approve',
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
foreach( $comments as $comment ) { 
$tot_stars +=  get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true );
}
$no_of_comments = get_comments_number( $post_id );
$avg_rating = ($tot_stars / $no_of_comments);
```

This logic works when I include it from this file however, I would like to `echo $avg_rating` on another PHP file, how may I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would [set a post meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) on the post, containing your calculated value. Be sure to update it whenever someone rates a comment.

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'avg_comment_rating', $avg_rating);
```

Then [use it elsewhere](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) e.g., in the loop:

```
$avg_rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'avg_comment_rating', true);
```

Comment: I am having some trouble echoing the output still. I believe I need a little more guidance on where to incorporate the `update_post_meta` and `$avg_rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'avg_comment_rating', true);` for my code above how would I arrange it so it correctly stores the `$avg_rating` and in the other document `echo $avg_rating`?

Comment: You store the value after you've calculated it, and then you use it where you need it.

Comment: So I would just add `update_post_meta($post_id, 'avg_comment_rating', $avg_rating);` after the code from my plugin above?

Comment: I have been toying with the code, and still cannot get it to output into my custom post template. In my plugin I have http://pastebin.com/BHr71wbg and in my custom post template I have `$avg_rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'avg_comment_rating', true);
 echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'avg_comment_rating', true);` Why won't this work? From my plugin, I can get the `$avg_rating` to display on comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. save the variable in a database
2. save the value in a session variable
3. save it as a cookie
4. continue using includes